# Curl giving 503 Service Unavailable in response

Tags: php, curl

My URL "www.example.com" is working in browser but when I get response via curl of URL "www.example.com" I get 503 service unavailable response.

I used the following code:

```
 $url = 'http://www.example.com';
   $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $JsonResponse = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
    print_r($http_code);die;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the remote server requires specific HTTP headers (cookies for example), like a session token or a language preference.

You have to analyze the HTTP traffic sent from your browser to the remote server and find the required HTTP headers yourself. I recommend a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

An example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: foo=bar
Connection: keep-alive
```

Assuming the remote server requires clients to send a cookie with the name `foo`, he will probably send you a 503 or 400 error message in the case you omit it. You have to send the cookie from cURL as well in order to get a successful response, acting like a regular client.

Comment: I analyzed and add required custom header but still getting 503 error message.

Comment: @versha: Can you provide us with some more information what you are actually sending?

Comment: We get response when we access "http://www.example.com" through localhost but from remote server , we get 503 service unavaliable error.

Comment: can you confirm your remote server can even access public internet sites? This may have nothing to do with curl and more to do with your public Internet accessibility on your remote server. If you can remotely connect to the remote server (via RDP or similar), can you pull up a browser on that server to connect to any public internet site? The server's firewall may be blocking these connections.